# Querying Postgres SQL JSON Column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a json column (json_col) in a postgres database with the following structure:

```
{
   "event1":{
      "START_DATE":"6/18/2011",
      "END_DATE":"7/23/2011",
      "event_type":"active with prior experience"
   },
   "event2":{
      "START_DATE":"8/20/11",
      "END_DATE":"2/11/2012",
      "event_type":"active"
   }
}
```

[example of table structure][1]

How can I make a select statement in postgres to return the start_date and end_date with a where statement where "event_type" like "active"?

Attempted Query:

```
select person_id, json_col#>>'START_DATE' as event_start, json_col#>>'END_DATE' as event_end
from data
where json_col->>'event_type' like '%active%';
```

Returns empty columns.

Expected Response:

```
event_start  
6/18/2011
8/20/2011
```

Comment: Your query and your error message don't match.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. When I corrected the where statement in the query (see edited question) it now returns empty columns.

Comment: The `#>>` operator needs an array as the right hand argument, e.g. `json_col #>> '{event1,START_DATE}'`

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? Both "events" would qualify for being `active`. Which start and end date do you want to retrieve? Can you please [edit] your question and add the expected output?

Comment: The goal is I want to query event_type across both events and have a response that indicates the start_date for both events. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to unnest your json structure, ignoring the top level keys and just getting the top level values.  You can do this with jsonb_each, looking at resulting column named 'value'.  You would put the function call in the FROM list as a lateral join (but since it is a function call, you don't need to specify the LATERAL keyword, it is implicit)

```
select value->>'START_DATE' from data, jsonb_each(json_col) 
    where value->>'event_type' like '%active%';
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!